# iPad-like pop-over in Sencha touch

Tags: popup, sencha-touch, overlay

I want to create an iPad-like pop-over with a login form in Sencha touch. How can I do this?

Comment: I was able to show the popover. But did you happened to dismiss it on a button tap? Because by setting `hideOnMaskTap: true` I can achieve that on background tap. I couldn't figure out on button tap.

Comment: it was as simple as I guessed `gkPopover.hide();` add this in any button handler so yo u can dismiss the popover on a button tap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try making a normal Ext.Panel to look like a popover

```
var gkpopover = new Ext.Panel({
id :'gkpopoverpanel',
floating:true,
modal:true,
width:'100px',
height:'100px',                                             });
```

*Note:* Never forget to set height and width.

and to Show

```
gkpopover.show('pop');
```

hope this makes sense.

Comment: also you can add `centered: true` to keep the popover in center of screen.

Answer (score 4):

On sencha touch 2, floating is depreciated. I've modified @geekay code to;

```js
        //show info popover?
    var popoverpanel = new Ext.Panel({
        modal:true,
        left:'10%',
        top:'10%',
        width:'80%',
        height:'80%',
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        html:data.info
    });
    Ext.Viewport.add(popoverpanel);
    popoverpanel.show('pop');
```

Credits go to him!

Answer (score 0):

As [this post points out](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?241192-showBy-function-doesn-t-display-pointing-rectangle-%28x-anchor-element%29), sencha have very exactly what you need.

Try this :

```
new Ext.Panel({
fullscreen : true,
items      : [
    {
        xtype  : 'toolbar',
        docked : 'top',
        items  : [
            {
                text    : 'Open',
                handler : function (button) {
                    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
                        height : 200,
                        width  : 200,
                        html   : 'Hello'
                    });

                    panel.showBy(button, 'tr-bc?');
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]});
```